# Why do strings work, but character and int arrays do not work in a pointer array?

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers, character

I understand if I add the arrays, st and st2, to give it space in the memory, and then add it to the pointer array, it shouldn't be a problem:

```
/* works */
int st[] = {0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
int st2[]= {0,31,29,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
int *day_tab[]= {
        st,
        st2
};
```

But without first giving it space in memory, why do strings specifically work?
The code below gives an error:

```
int *day_tab[]= {
        {0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31},
        {0,31,29,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31}
};
```

so does the code below:

```
char *day_tab[]= {
        {'0','1','\0'},
        {'0','1','\0'}
};
```

but the code below works

```
char *day_tab[]= {
        "01",
        "01"
};
```

Comment: "I understand if I add the arrays to give it space in the memory," - what do you mean by "add the arrays"?

Comment: Let me edit the question

Comment: `"0"` is an array with static storage duration. Braced lists aren't objects of any sort (they only provide initial values for whatever you are initializing)

Comment: Edited it again. Thank you @M.M. Could you please elaborate if possible.

Comment: @hamzasiddiq You still haven't explained what you mean by "add the arrays".

Comment: Aah I see @Dai. By add the arrays, I meant st and st2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
int st[] = {0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
int st2[]= {0,31,29,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
int *day_tab[]= {
        st,
        st2
};
```

Is three arrays: two of integers (with their own storage), and one array of two elements which are pointers to the first two arrays.

However, this is not valid:

```
int *day_tab[]= {
        {0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31},
        {0,31,29,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31}
};
```

As before you have declared an array of pointers to integers, but pointers to what?  Those braced lists are not storage locations, they cannot be pointed to.

Your final example is basically valid but dangerous:

```
char *day_tab[]= {
        "01",
        "01"
};
```

It is an array of two pointers to characters, and those pointers are initialized with string literals.  String literals are very special in that they are actually stored somewhere, usually in read-only memory, and they can be shared (so the "01" string used twice can be stored just once).  Braced lists don't have this feature in C, it's only for string literals.

The reason the final code is dangerous is that it is `char*` not `const char*`.  The non-const type is accepted for reasons of backward compatibility but is not a good idea because modifying the data in a literal string is not allowed.  So you're setting yourself up for a potential disaster if you actually use those pointers to write to the "01" string storage.

Answer (score 1):

The following works

```
int *day_tab[]= {
        st,
        st2
};
```

because when you access an array, it is converted to a pointer to first element (there are few *[exceptions](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)* to this rule). So, when you used `st` and `st2` array in initialisation, they will convert to pointer to first element of respective array and , after initialisation, pointer `day_tab[0]` will point to first element of array `st` and pointer `day_tab[1]` will point to first element of array `st1`.

In the code snippet

```
int *day_tab[]= {
        {0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31},
        {0,31,29,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31}
};
```

and

```
char *day_tab[]= {
        {'0','1','\0'},
        {'0','1','\0'}
};
```

you are trying to initialise the pointers of array `day_tab` with more than one initialiser. Note that pointers are **scalar types** and from C11 Standard#6.7.9p11

> 11 The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression, optionally enclosed in braces....

However, you can use the [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) to initialise the pointers of `day_tab` `int` pointer array, like this:

```
    int *day_tab[]= {
        (int []){0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31},
        (int []){0,31,29,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31}
    };
```

This will initialise the pointers `day_tab[0]` and `day_tab[1]` to point to the first element of respective array.
Similarly, for `char` pointers array, you can do

```
    char *day_tab[]= {
        (char []){'0','1','\0'},
        (char []){'0','1','\0'}
    };
```

When you do

```
char *day_tab[]= {
        "01",
        "01"
};
```

It works because string literals are array of characters and when it is used in the expression it will convert to pointer to type `char` that point to first element of array. So, this initialises the pointers `day_tab[0]` and `day_tab[1]` to point to the first element of **read only** string literal `"01"`.